# How to upload video to S3 using Amplify or RNFetchBlob?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, react-native, aws-amplify

I'm using `react-native-image-picker` to get a file path of a video on my iOS simulator phone for my react native app. How do i use this to upload to S3 using Amplify?

```
import ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-picker';
import RNFetchBlob from 'react-native-fetch-blob';

class App extends Component {

 constructor(props) {
    super(props)

   this.state = {
     vidFileName: '',
     fileURI: '',
   }

    this.putFileInS3 = this.putFileInS3.bind(this);  
 }

  pickVideo = async () => {

    const options = {
       mediaType: 'video'
      };
      ImagePicker.launchImageLibrary(options, (response) => {
          console.log('Response = ', response);

         this.setState({ 
            vidFileName: response.fileName,
            fileURI: response.uri,
          });

         this.putFileInS3();
     }
  }

 readFile = (somefilePath) => {
     return RNFetchBlob.fs.readFile(somefilePath, 'base64').then(data => new 
      Buffer(data, 'base64'));
    } 


putFileInS3 = async () => 
  {
     RNFetchBlob.fs.readFile(this.fileURI).then(buffer => {
       Storage.put(vidFileName, buffer, { contentType: 'video/mp4' })
       conole.log('successfully uploaded video to bucket');
     }).catch(e => {
       console.log(e);
     });

  }
```

I am trying to follow this: https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/storage, in the Upload an image in React Native app section. But maybe i've missed something? Can you help please?

```
Error: file:///Users/xxxxxxxxxx/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/xxxxxxxxx/data/Containers/Data/Application/5CxxxxxxxxxxxxxC79/tmp/4xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.MOV . <-URI
App.js:130 Error: file not exists
    at createErrorFromErrorData (NativeModules.js:146)
    at NativeModules.js:95
    at MessageQueue.__invokeCallback (MessageQueue.js:397)
    at MessageQueue.js:127
    at MessageQueue.__guard (MessageQueue.js:297)
    at MessageQueue.invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue (MessageQueue.js:126)
    at debuggerWorker.js:72
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  putFileInS3 = async () => {
    RNFetchBlob.fetch('PUT', link,
      {
        'Content-Type': undefined
      },
      RNFetchBlob.wrap(Platform.OS === "android" ? this.state.fileURI :
        this.state.fileURI.replace("file://", "")))
      .then((resp) => {
        this.onImageUploadSuccess(resp)
      }).catch((err) => {
        this.onUploadFailure(err)
      })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This package works perfectly to send data to your bucket in S3, [react-native-aws3](https://github.com/benjreinhart/react-native-aws3).

If you want any assistance in using the package, do comment.

Comment: I have used this successfully before, but in the interest of security, i'd rather stick to AWS Amplify's method as the user would be signed in through 'withAuthenticator'

Comment: @chai86 Did you find a solution to this?