# Upload Image to aws S3 using using react native after taking photo using react native camera

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-s3

I am beginner in react native.I want to upload files to aws s3 once after taking the photo in using react native camera. I am able to take picture using react native camera. Now, I need to upload to s3 bucket. When I search for this, I get many documents and I get confused how to use this.

I have done file uploading to amazon s3 and downloading form s3 using php. But in react native I am not getting how to do this as I am a beginner . I searched in aws s3 file upload documents there I got using php, java and .Net etc..But I did not get for react native.

Can anyone help me to do this.

My code to take image in react native is,

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text,TouchableOpacity, View} from 'react-native';
import ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-picker';
import RNS3 from 'react-native-aws3';
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  takePic(){
    ImagePicker.showImagePicker({},(responce)=>{
      console.log(responce);
      const file ={
        uri : responce.path,
        name : responce.fileName,
        type :  responce.type,
      }
      console.log(file);
      const config ={
        keyPrefix :'uploads/',
        bucket : '**',
        region :'***',
        accessKey:'***',
        secretKey :'***',
        successActionStatus :201
      }
      RNS3.put(file ,config)
      .then((responce) => {
        console.log(responce);
      })
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>Welcome v</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.takePic.bind(this)}>
          <Text>Take Picture</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});
```

When I select the picture from galary / cliked new photo it gives me below error,

```
02-05 09:10:52.738 12357 12389 I ReactNativeJS: { uri: '/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/image-cb48f179-5b00-4e0a-93ef-74206f76c4e4.jpg',
02-05 09:10:52.738 12357 12389 I ReactNativeJS:   name: 'image-cb48f179-5b00-4e0a-93ef-74206f76c4e4.jpg',
02-05 09:10:52.738 12357 12389 I ReactNativeJS:   type: 'image/jpeg' }
02-05 09:10:52.738 12357 12389 E ReactNativeJS: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNativeAws.default.put')
```

How to resolve this ReactNativeJS: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNativeAws.default.put').

Can you please help me out to resolve this.

Comment: Check out this link [aws s3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54470239/how-to-upload-video-to-s3-using-amplify-or-rnfetchblob/54474116#54474116)

Comment: Thank you Ron . I have used the same But I am getting undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNativeAws.default.put') error . Even I tried to searched to resolved . But I did not get any error.

Comment: Can you please see my uploaded code and help me to resolve this.

Comment: Hello Ron , Do I need to make any configuration in aws s3?

Comment: you have to make the bucket public in order to store data in s3

Comment: I have made it public only. As I mentioned in above description I have done it while uploading file and downloading using php

Comment: And in permission ,{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowPublicAccess",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:PutObjectVersionAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::s3merahkee/uploads/*"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: The error in  RNS3.put(file ,config) method, it gives undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNativeAws.default.put')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolve my error :):).Finally, It got worked after 4 days. So happy.

I have installed react-native-file-upload. Now it works Perfectly.

npm install react-native-file-upload --save